# Error upon getting transactions received by address using bitcoin-cli

Tags: bitcoin, cryptocurrency, bitcoind

I've got problem with printing transactions received on address.
On my machine I've got full sync node

[image]

but still cannot get transactions on address. Command which I use:

**bitcoin-cli getreceivedbyaddress ADDRESS**

Result:

```
error code: -4
error message:
Address not found in wallet
```

Is there anything more that I should do?

Answer (score 0):

`getreceivedbyaddress` is a wallet RPC query. It queries your own wallet.
Bitcoind does not  maintain a full per-address index of the blockchain.
To query any address you should use `importaddress` RPC call

> importaddress "address" ( "label" rescan p2sh ) Adds an address or
> script (in hex) that can be watched as if it were in your wallet but
> cannot be used to spend. Requires a new wallet backup.

rescan is on by default and rescanning can take some time.